# Will this query ever execute looking at my query plan(Explain)

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database

I have been trying to run this query all night long and only to wake up in the morning and still see it executing ! You can imagine the disappointment. Well, it's a pretty large query. I was hoping someone with knowledge in query optimisation could have a look at the query and it's Explain and see if it could be optimized ?

Comment: The Last 2 Join Statements are the cause of everlasting execution. When i delete them, the query can run with a Limit of 1000 but if i added those 2 last queries and even set a limit to 300 it takes forever

Comment: The 2 sub querys might not be quick but shouldn't be that slow (it is effectively not using an index to join the results of those to the rest of the query). Depending on you exact table structure (ie, is AS_No unqiue) you might be able to avoid using the sub queries. However I suspect a bigger issue might be your join of update_detail against itself where you do not appear to have an index on the time, plus you are doing a calculation on each row (ie, adding 59 seconds). You have a key on Update_id, but as you are only checking on that for inequality I don't think that will help.

Comment: COuld you post update_detail table? Looks like you miss some relation ccolumn in the first JOIN

Comment: @StanislavL i just added the schema, is it enough or you want the create query ?

Comment: @Kickstart thank you for your reply. AS No is not unique. AS No is list of numbers belonging to an Update_ID which is why i am comparing based on the amount of them(Count). Added my schema :)

Comment: JOIN
    update_detail u_d2 ON u_d2.Time >= u_d1.Time
        and u_d2.Time <= u_d1.Time + interval 59 second
        and u_d2.Update_ID > u_d1.Update_ID and u_d2.type=u_d1.type

Comment: What if you add more conditions into the join? e.g. by type. I think you are trying to find next update (within 1 minute)

Comment: @StanislavL i am looking for duplicate Updates that have the same IP in the announce_update table and occur within 1 minute timeframe. But Time is on the update_detail table so that is why i joined the table as well.

Answer (score 1):

According to discussion in the comments the FROM section should be like this

```
FROM
    update_detail u_d1
        JOIN
    update_detail u_d2 ON u_d2.Time >= u_d1.Time
        and u_d2.Time <= u_d1.Time + interval 59 second
        and u_d2.Update_ID > u_d1.Update_ID
        and u_d2.Peer_IP=u_d1.Peer_IP
```